# Ubuntu Bluetooth speakers with mic no sound with A2DP and bad sound otherwise

Tags: sound, alsa, headset, bluetooth-speaker, a2dp

Just bought Boat Stone 352 bluetooth speakers with mic( also supports aux) but it won't connect properly with ubuntu.

Originally it would show as headset after connecting with bluetooth and there was no sound with default and only A2DP profile. Searched for some answers most of which included pulse audio or blueman. I already had pulse audio as I had problem with HDMI screen sound earlier, but still followed answer and also installed blueman but none of those solutions fixed my problem. Then I actually upgraded my ubuntu to latest 23 and lost all audio profiles even in built wasn't working. Read a solution and used command  `sudo alsa force-reload` which worked to enable my in-built speakers and two profiles of bluetooth speakers. One of which is working giving bad quality audio while other with A2DP is not giving any audio output.

Please if anyone have solution to my specific my situation, please do help. I want to enable my speaker with A2DP.

Attaching screenshots for how my sound profiles look in settings:

[These are the profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37yHg.png)
[this is 2nd profile with A2DP without audio output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJBR6.png)
[3rd profile with bad quality output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1RcX.png)